# Line on top of detail on new page

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm developing a report where I use a subreport to have a grid/table with list of instances. Everything is ok till the subreport is not spitted by new page. I need to have a horizontal line on the top of the first detail on new page.
Here is how it looks like now:
[image]

And here is my definition:

[image]

Please have you got any idea?

Thank you all,
Martin

Comment: so you want the line only to appear every page of the report? then why not use the page header?

Comment: I need to have a table, so I need the line to have it on each detail band.

Comment: Put 1 top line and no bottom line.